# Java TimeZone.setDefault

Tags: java, timezone

`TimeZone.setDefault` timezone doesn't seem to support daylight savings time. If I leave the default (without using the function `setDefault`) the application comes up displaying dates in EST/EDT. But if ever I want to change the time zone (I use a combo box of  `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`), I can only select EST (and daylight savings is ignored).

Looking in the documentation there's all sorts of ways to determine daylight savings of a timezone, but it doesn't look like it can be set. Any ideas how I can force a timezone to use daylight savings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use daylight savings by referring to times when daylight savings is active.

The only way to tell it you want daylight savings even when it is not daylight savings is to create your own TimeZone, but that doesn't sound like a good idea. Or you can use a timezone which has the time offset you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. how do i get at those "times when daylight savings is active" because my TimeZone.getAvailableIds() is not showing them...

Comment: Ahh i was doing something goofy preventing me from seeing them... my bad, your answer is indeed correct

Comment: There are timezones which support daylight saving and those which don't.  For those which do, the periods when they have daylight savings varies and is largely political. e.g. London was in daylight savings for three years between 1968 and 1972. Moscow stopped having daylight savings in 2010.

Comment: Yeah this issue was more complex then it looks at first blush.. actually its been on our companies defect pile for about a year now glad i can finally close it out (after its properly tested of course)